# Angular 13 upgrade error: error TS2709: Cannot use namespace 'OrderedMap' as a type

Tags: angular

I am working on upgrading our app from Angular 9 to Angular 13, one release at a time. After upgrading from 12 to 13 and resolving errors, I'm stuck on one error that I don't know how to resolve. Has anyone else encountered this issue?

```
Error: node_modules/@types/prosemirror-model/index.d.ts:1132:40 - error TS2709: Cannot use namespace 'OrderedMap' as a type.

1132     nodes: { [name in N]: NodeSpec } | OrderedMap<NodeSpec>;
                                            ~~~~~~~~~~

Error: node_modules/@types/prosemirror-model/index.d.ts:1139:41 - error TS2709: Cannot use namespace 'OrderedMap' as a type.

1139     marks?: { [name in M]: MarkSpec } | OrderedMap<MarkSpec> | null | undefined;
                                             ~~~~~~~~~~

Error: node_modules/@types/prosemirror-schema-list/index.d.ts:44:40 - error TS2709: Cannot use namespace 'OrderedMap' as a type.

44     nodes: { [name in N]: NodeSpec } | OrderedMap<NodeSpec>,
                                          ~~~~~~~~~~

Error: node_modules/@types/prosemirror-schema-list/index.d.ts:47:81 - error TS2709: Cannot use namespace 'OrderedMap' as a type.

47 ): { [name in (N | "ordered_list" | "bullet_list" | "list_item")]: NodeSpec } | OrderedMap<NodeSpec>;
                                                                                   ~~~~~~~~~~

✖ Failed to compile.
```

My package.json file is:

```
{
  "name": "argon-dashboard-pro-angular",
  "version": "1.1.1",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "node --max_old_space_size=8000 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng serve --configuration development",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "install:clean": "rm -rf node_modules/ && rm -rf package-lock.json && npm install && npm start"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "13.3.12",
    "@angular/common": "^13.3.12",
    "@angular/compiler": "13.3.12",
    "@angular/core": "^13.3.12",
    "@angular/forms": "13.3.12",
    "@angular/localize": "13.3.12",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "13.3.12",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "13.3.12",
    "@angular/router": "13.3.12",
    "@auth0/angular-jwt": "^5.0.2",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro": "^5.13.0",
    "@fullcalendar/core": "4.4.0",
    "@fullcalendar/daygrid": "4.4.0",
    "@fullcalendar/interaction": "4.4.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^12.1.2",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-buttons": "^6.4.1",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-common": "^2.0.2",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-dateinputs": "^5.3.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-dialog": "^5.2.3",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-dropdowns": "^5.5.1",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-editor": "^2.5.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-inputs": "^7.5.2",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-intl": "^3.1.2",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-l10n": "^3.0.3",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-popup": "^4.0.3",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-sortable": "^4.0.4",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-toolbar": "^4.1.3",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-tooltip": "^3.1.6",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-treeview": "^5.4.3",
    "@progress/kendo-data-query": "^1.5.4",
    "@progress/kendo-date-math": "^1.5.4",
    "@progress/kendo-drawing": "^1.16.3",
    "@progress/kendo-licensing": "^1.2.1",
    "@progress/kendo-recurrence": "^1.0.1",
    "@progress/kendo-theme-bootstrap": "^4.9.1",
    "@swimlane/ngx-datatable": "^20.0.0",
    "angular2-promise-buttons": "^5.0.3",
    "azure-storage": "^2.10.3",
    "bootstrap": "4.4.1",
    "chart.js": "2.7.3",
    "clipboard": "2.0.4",
    "core-js": "3.6.4",
    "d3-scale": "3.2.1",
    "devextreme": "19.2.6",
    "devextreme-angular": "19.2.6",
    "dropzone": "5.5.1",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "fullcalendar": "3.10.1",
    "jspdf": "^2.5.1",
    "list.js": "1.5.0",
    "mobius1-selectr": "2.4.13",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.31",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "5.3.2",
    "ngx-chips": "^2.2.2",
    "ngx-clipboard": "^12.2.0",
    "ngx-image-cropper": "^3.2.1",
    "ngx-print": "^1.2.0-beta.5",
    "ngx-toastr": "^12.1.0",
    "nouislider": "11.1.0",
    "quill": "1.3.7",
    "rxjs": "^6.6.7",
    "stream": "0.0.2",
    "sweetalert2": "8.16.3",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^13.3.11",
    "@angular-devkit/core": "^13.3.11",
    "@angular/cli": "13.3.11",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "13.3.12",
    "@angular/language-service": "13.3.12",
    "@types/chart.js": "^2.9.24",
    "@types/googlemaps": "^3.40.5",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "2.0.8",
    "@types/node": "13.7.6",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "8.6.2",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "4.6.4"
  }
}
```

If anyone has suggestions, they'd be greatly appreciated!

Comment: do you know which library OrderedMap is coming from? Potentially it needs a complementary `@types` package downloaded

Comment: or potentially there is a newer version of that `@types` file that may be needed.

Comment: @DanOswalt I work with Christie. I don't know what library is using them. Do you know of a way to find out?

Answer (score 0):

Not a true solution, but we narrowed the issue down to @progress/kendo-angular-editor; and since we stopped using that editor in favor of another one, we just uninstalled that package and that solved the issue.